# Angular service for a library that dynamically generates objects with async methods

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to write an Angular service wrapper for the following non-Angular library with classical async success/error handlers, so that it would integrate nicely into Angular app using promises and being Angular-aware.

In a typically case, this would just be a matter of writing a facade that wraps the async call with `$q` promise:

```
doSomething: function(param){
  return $q(function(resolve, reject){
     nonAngularSvc.doSomethingAsync(
        function onSuccess(result) { resolve(result); },
        function onError(error) { reject(error); }
     );
  });
}
```

The problem is that not only that the library - which queries a backend and returns a `table` object containing `item` objects - but also the dynamically created `table` and `item` objects, have async methods. For example:

```
nonAngularSvc.query(onSuccess, onError); // onSuccess returns a table object

tableObj.update(onSuccess, onError); // updates all pending changes
tableObj.addItem(item, onSuccess, onError); // adds a new record to the table

itemObj.update(onSuccess, onError); // updates only the current item

// etc...
```

So, now, even if I wrapped the `query` method, I still get the objects with non-Angular async methods.

Ideally, I would want to invoke the `update` function directly from the View:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in table">
  <button ng-click="item.update()">update</button>
  <input ng-model="item.data">
</div>
<button ng-click="table.update()">Save All</button>
```

This, of course, will not trigger a digest and any updated properties would not be reflected until the next digest.

Alternatively, I could handle this in the controller:

```
$scope.update = function(item){
  item.update(function(){
    $scope.$apply(); // this is ugly
  });
}
```

But I would like to avoid sprinkling `$scope.$apply` everywhere.

How do I wrap these async methods of dynamically created `table` and `item` objects? Is there a good practice to handle this?

Here's a [plunker for illustration](http://plnkr.co/edit/pDcTldeKMcACiJHa8ky2?p=preview)

Comment: You *could* monkey-patch the methods of the table and item objects to use promises, like you described with your "facade". Too much of a kludge?

Comment: @Chris, actually, while writing this question, I was thinking about that approach (if I understand correctly what you meant by "monkey-patch"). Thanks. Yeah, a bit of a kludge :)

Comment: It seems to me (seat-of-the-pants judgement, thus comment not answer) that you're essentially building a translation layer between two APIs, and so there's not really a way around this kind of wrapping. You could aim for more generality, e.g. a wrapper that translates *any* success/error callback type method to a promise method, given that the library you're working with is sufficiently consistent.

Comment: @Chris, it's not fully consistent; for example, `addItem` expects an additional input that `update` doesn't have. But yeah, a wrapper is some manifestation of a translation layer. I'll wait for better approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, while writing the question and building an illustrative example, I thought that Javascript, being a dynamic language, can actually make it relatively easy - I'll just need to create a derived object for each dynamically received object and overwrite its async methods, while retaining prototypical inheritance for all other properties:

Here's a high level approach:

```
// wrapper for query
query: function(input) {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {

    // SPHelper is the non-Angular service referred in the question
    SPHelper.query(input, function(result) {

      var wrappedResults = [];    
      angular.forEach(result, function(item) {
        var newItem = wrapItem(item); // create a derived object
        this.push(newItem);
      }, wrappedResults);

      resolve(wrappedResults);
    });
  });
}

function wrapItem(item) {
  var newItem = Object.create(item);
  var updateFn = item.update;
  // overwrite the async update function with a promise-base async
  newItem.update = function() {
    return $q(function(resolve) {
      // invoke the original
      updateFn.call(newItem, function(result) {
        resolve(result);
      });
    }).then(); // .then seems to be required to actually trigger a digest
  };
  return newItem;
}
```

Then I can accomplish the following:

```
<button ng-click="item.update()">update</button>
```

and have the View reflect any VM changes.

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YvvZgAq7QDfuReHxhU4U?p=preview)